# Popup ContextMenu with Alt key, select Item with code by name

Tags: vb.net

I would like to open ContextMenuStrip with code and automatically set an (recommended) item.
Here I got two problems:

```
Private Sub myfrm_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
                          Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Me.Close()

    If e.Alt Then
        e.Handled = True
        Dim pLoc As Point = New Point(Me.Location.X + myDGV.Location.X + 100, _
                                      Me.Location.Y + myDGV.Location.Y + 100)
        myContext.Show(pLoc)
    End If
End Sub
```

1) How to detect if ONLY alt key is pressed and no other key?
2) How to automatically select (not run, only select) an item "ExitToolStripMenuItem" after popping up this context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question has a straightforward answer:

```
ExitToolStripMenuItem.Select()
```

Each item in the StripMenu has its own "independent" object which you can access directly.

Your first question can become a bit trickier. The `Alt Key` is a modifier and is expected to be used in combination with other key, why not using it as intended? By relying on events (withouts hooks, or anything like this), you would have to set up a global (boolean) variable and combine `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events (and put all your code in the KeyUp event); but it will not be straightforward: every time you press Alt this information is stored (because, as said, it is expected to be used in this way: pressed in combination with other key) and thus it can become a bit difficult to determine whether other key is pressed or not in combination with Alt depending upon the order (if Alt was pressed before than the other key or not). I recommend you to avoid all this hassle and just rely on Alt + other key.

Comment: Hello varocarbas, thanks for help. Select is working! Based on your other explanation I have to consider what will I do. Thanks for that also.